# Corba chunked response

Tags: corba, keep-alive, chunked-encoding

Is it possible corba service response one request multiple times? 
In my case, corba service collects a bunch of data which takes a long time for request. In order to reduce delay client receives response, we want service responses soon when the size of collected data reach 1024k. For example, the total data sizes is 10M, service responses client 10 times on one connection.

My understanding is that corba server should cache connection between client and server, and deliver new data on this cached one once a new data is available. The client, on other handle, should do while loop for incoming response. Either client or server should not close connection until server says all data is connected. This procedure is similar to that in chunked response in Http protocol.

I appreciate if you can provide some tips or sample links in this area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CORBA server side is only able to send the data to the client when the server application code returns the function call. If you have just one operation in IDL that returns 10M, than the ORB can only transmit that data to the client when the operation has finished. In order to allow the ORB to send the data it has you have to modify your IDL and add a way for the client to start the operation and than poll for chunks of data to be available. Each implementation of the poll than returns with one chunk.

Some examples of how to do this are part of [TAO](http://download.dre.vanderbilt.edu). You can find the examples under ACE_wrappers/TAO/examples/Content_Server. It also has an example where the server pushes the data to the client when a chunk is available.